# How can I find the error code thrown in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have this code:

```
IF (@@ROWCOUNT != 1)
    THROW 50004,'mark_test - Problem setting test status to Marked',1
```

I know I can get the error message like this:

```
SET @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()
```

But how can I get the number 50004 ?

Comment: All error-handling functions are listed in `TRY-CATCH` documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976(v=sql.120).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`ERROR_NUMBER`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms175069.aspx) function

> Returns the error number of the error that caused the CATCH block of a
>   TRY…CATCH construct to be run.

**DEMO**

```
BEGIN TRY
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1

    IF ( @@ROWCOUNT != 1 )
      THROW 50004, 'mark_test - Problem setting test status to Marked', 1
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT Error_number=Error_number(),
           Error_message=Error_message()
END CATCH
```

**Result**

```
Error_number    Error_message
50004           mark_test - Problem setting test status to Marked
```

Comment: If passing back from a stored procedure, would I declare this as an INT?

Comment: @Marilou - yes you can make it as `INT`. Because return type of `ERROR_MESSAGE` function is `INT`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@@ERROR` variable. See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188790.aspx)